# How to detect if there was a error in ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, stderr

I have a ghostscript command, when the file I input is wrong, ghostscript fail and print a error message.

So far so good, I do a simple script apply the command on multiple files, and tell me how many files failed.

But ghostscript print error on stdout, and nothing to stdout.

While searching, I found the `-sstdout` flag, but in that case, everything goes to stderr and nothing to stdout.

Is there a way to simply and programatically tell if ghostscript encountered a error?

(A ugly workaround would be to search for 'error' in stdout, but that s just plain bad).

Is there a way to tell ghostscript to use stdout and stderr like thoses are supposed to be used? For separate standard and error output?

Comment: I really, really doubt that Ghostscript is printing errors to stdin..... As far as I recall errors do in fact go to stderr, while normal back channel output goes to stdout, which seems to be what you are asking for. In addition to your answer below you can also use 1> and 2> to redirect stdout and stderr on the command line. I wouldn't rely on -q suppressing all messages, it won't.

Comment: @KenS: Sorry, brain fart, it output to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve found another workaround, since I don t need stdout, I added the flags `-q -sstdout=%stderr`.

`-q` suspress all non error message (in my case)

`-sstdout=%stderr` redirect stdout to stderr, in my case it mean the error messages.